# Converting Hexadecimal cell value to binary in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, binary, hex

I am trying to convert a column of hexadecimal values to binary values and then write the binary values to a binary file. However, I am having trouble with the conversion of the hex values to binary...

I found this thread: [Convert hex value string to Binary string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37898152/convert-hex-value-string-to-binary-string)

I have been trying to do as the answers suggest and convert each hex character to binary and then append the results to a string representing the full binary number. However, I am getting errors when trying to convert my hexadecimal string characters... Here is what I am currently trying to do:

```
Dim hexString As String
Dim binaryString As String
hexString = ""
binaryString = ""
Dim rangeOfCells As Range
Set rangeOfCells = Range ("C5: C100")
Dim hexCell As Range

For Each hexCell In rangeOfCells.Cells
    If Not isEmpty(hexCell.value) Then
        hexString = hexCell.Value
        Dim counter As Integer
        For counter = 1 to Len(hexString)
            binaryString = binaryString & Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(Mid(hexString, counter, 1), 16), 2)
        Next
    End If
Next
```

I keep getting this error on the line converting the `hexString` character to binary and appending the value to the `binaryString`:

> Run-time error '424': Object required

I have tried simplifying the line of code and continue to get the error event when just trying to convert my `hexString` to an Int (ie: `Convert.ToInt32(hexString)`).

Any help on this issue is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `Convert.ToString` is VB.NET, not VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use hex2bin or some of the other functions mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741003/how-can-you-convert-hex-to-bin-one-character-at-a-time-in-excel-2010) post

Answer (score 2):

You're getting an 'Object Required' run-time error because `Option Explicit` isn't specified.

With `Option Explicit` you would've had a compile-time error telling you that `Convert` isn't declared anywhere.

Reason being, it's a static class in the .NET framework, in the `System` namespace: it has nothing whatsoever to do with VBA.

If the value to convert is relatively small, then you can use the `HEX2BIN` worksheet function:

```
Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.Hex2Bin(myHexValue)
```

If the function throws an error, then the value is too large and you need to implement your own. This site has plenty of readily-usable implementations.