# Code to convert from Hexa to Binary Excel VBA a large number

Tags: excel, vba, binary, hex

I'm trying to convert 6E29210100 (hexa) to binary. 
With smaller hexa numbers, the code works fine. and I don't know why.
I would like it was working to 10 characters at least.

```
Dim HexNum As String
Dim BinNum As String
Dim lHexNum As Long
Dim i As Integer

Public Sub Teste()

    HexNum = "6E29210100"

    HexToBin (HexNum)

    MsgBox "Bin: " & HexToBin
    BinNum = vbNullString

End Sub

Public Function HexToBin(Optional HexNum As String) As String

   On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

   i = 0

   lHexNum = Val("&h" & HexNum)

   Do
      If lHexNum And 2 ^ i Then
         BinNum = "1" & BinNum
      Else
         BinNum = "0" & BinNum
      End If
      i = i + 1
   Loop Until 2 ^ i > lHexNum

   HexToBin = BinNum

ErrorHandler:

End Function
```

Code returns:       00101001001000010000000100000000

Right answer: ‭0110111000101001001000010000000100000000‬

Comment: Why is the parameter optional, and why is there a `HexNum` module-scope variable? That makes the `HexNum` parameter hide the `HexNum` field, which makes debugging much more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: You want the `HexToBin (HexNum)` line to capture the returned value in a local variable, instead of re-invoking the function to show its output (very indirectly) in a msgbox.

Comment: Something is wrong with your algorithm. `"FFFF"`(-1) yields `1`.

Comment: I'm noob, sorry. I'm just starting with programming language in my internship experience. I just wanna convert a ten carachters hexa to bin number. It was my first try.

Comment: You're right. I haven't tried with FFFF.  I was using A1, B23, etc..

Comment: Do you have some tip for me to get what I want to do?

Comment: You could declare `Dim ptr As LongPtr` and output `BinNum = String(LenB(ptr) * 8, "1")` when `lHexNum < 0` to handle `-1` and that'll output 64x"1" or 32x"1", depending on pointer size on the machine running the code... but it kinda falls apart given other negatives - consider just bailing out if `lHexNum` is negative.

Comment: use the function here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741003/how-can-you-convert-hex-to-bin-one-character-at-a-time-in-excel-2010

Comment: @ScottCraner ah, nice find!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741003/how-can-you-convert-hex-to-bin-one-character-at-a-time-in-excel-2010)

Included only to help with the call of the function which OP had issues.

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim HexNum As String
    HexNum = "6E29210100"

    Dim BinNum As String
    BinNum = HEXtoBIN(HexNum)

    MsgBox BinNum

End Sub

Public Function HEXtoBIN(ByVal strHex As String) As String
    Dim c As Long, i As Long, b As String * 4, j As Long
    For c = 1 To Len(strHex)
        b = "0000"
        j = 0
        i = Val("&H" & Mid$(strHex, c, 1))
        While i > 0
            Mid$(b, 4 - j, 1) = i Mod 2
            i = i \ 2
            j = j + 1
        Wend
        HEXtoBIN = HEXtoBIN & b
    Next
    HEXtoBIN = RTrim$(HEXtoBIN)
End Function
```

[image]