# Hex 2 binary for large number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

working in projects, where I need to convert 5 bytes into binary in EXCEL, can anyone please help out Example - Hex A00080080 in to binary in excel cell

Comment: you will need vba, see function here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57578776/code-to-convert-from-hexa-to-binary-excel-vba-a-large-number

Answer (score 2):

With **Excel 365**, use:

```
=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,HEX2BIN(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1),4))
```

[image]

**Note:**

- Each hexal is converted into a 4-bit binary number and then all the 4-bits are concatenated.
- Because this is just a string-to-string translation, the original hex string can be almost unlimited in length.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that each hex value is effectively 0-15 (or 0-1111 in binary) to "walk" the hex number and do the conversion character by character within a custom VBA function:

```
Function fLargeHEX2BIN(strNumber As String) As String
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    Dim lngLen As Long
    lngLen = Len(strNumber)
    For lngLoop1 = 1 To lngLen
        fLargeHEX2BIN = fLargeHEX2BIN & Format(WorksheetFunction.Hex2Bin(Mid(strNumber, lngLoop1, 1)), "0000")
    Next lngLoop1
End Function
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

There are native bin2hex and hex2bin functions in most excel implementations/clones and they are horrendous (just look at the [examples given by M$](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hex2bin-function-a13aafaa-5737-4920-8424-643e581828c1)).

However, you can get around this even without scripts or advanced formula features but the solution is not exactly elegant...

```
=HEX2BIN(MID(A1,1,2),8)&HEX2BIN(MID(A1,3,2),8)&HEX2BIN(MID(A1,5,2),8)&HEX2BIN(MID(A1,7,2),8)&HEX2BIN(MID(A1,9,2),8)
```

NB: it requires precisely 2*5 hex characters as input

It can easily be extended further if need be, and also reduced for the probably more commonly required **version for 16 and 32 bits**, respectively:

```
=HEX2BIN(MID(A1,1,2),8)&HEX2BIN(MID(A1,3,2),8)
=HEX2BIN(MID(A1,1,2),8)&HEX2BIN(MID(A1,3,2),8)&HEX2BIN(MID(A1,5,2),8)&HEX2BIN(MID(A1,7,2),8)
```